# Invalid Outside Procedure error with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine several cells of data with the same label. There will either be 2 or 3 (also accounted for 1) repeated cells. I keep getting an invalid outside procedure error function. It highlights the "module module1" so I think it is something to do with defining my class, but I am not familar enough with VBA to figure it out.

```
Module Module1
Public Sub Main()
    Dim num As Integer
    num = 2
    Dim val As Integer
    val = 2
    While num <= 5031
        If StrComp(Cells(num, 3).Value, Cells((num + 1), 3).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 And StrComp(Cells(num, 3).Value, Cells((num + 1), 3).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Cells(val, 5) = Calls(num, 3).Value
            Cells(val, 6) = Add(Cells(num, 4).Value, Cells(num + 1, 4).Value, Cells(num + 2, 4).Value)
            num = num + 3
            val = val + 1
            End If
        ElseIf StrComp(Cells(num, 3).Value, Cells((num + 1), 3).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Cells(val, 5) = Calls(num, 3).Value
            Cells(val, 6) = Add(Cells(num, 4).Value, Cells(num + 1, 4).Value)
            num = num + 2
            val = val + 1
            End If
        Else
            Cells(val, 5) = Calls(num, 3).Value
            Cells(val, 6) = Cells(num, 4).Value
            num = num + 1
            val = val + 1
            End If

    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Delete `Module Module1` it's not valid in the code editor window.

Comment: I have tried that and I received a "sub or function not defined" error. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the extra `End If` statements.  VBA `If ... Then ... Else` format is as follows:

```
If choice Then
    Statements...
ElseIf nextChoice Then
    Statements...
...as Many Elseif's as you need
Else
    Statements...
End If
```

I believe that the VBA compiler is unable to recover from the extra `End If` statements

Comment: The "sub or function not defined error is coming from the statements: `Cells(val, 5) = Calls(num, 3).Value`.  The statement after it with the `Add(` could cause an error unless you've defined that function elsewhere.